# RubyMineで `before_save`が未定義だとされてしまう。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

RubyMineを使い始めたばかりで何か設定が足りていないのかもしれませんが、画像のように`before_save`の名前解決ができず警告が出されてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Rails自体は正常に動いておりますが、どこを調べればエラーを修正できるでしょうか？

#### 追記

`before_save`だけでなく`before_action`にも同様のエラーが出ます。また環境はrbenvを用いて`2.1.4`を使っています。

Comment: before_saveだけでなく。 has_many とか before_action とかもじゃないでしょうか。 英語にも同様の問題が報告されているようです(回答ついていませんが) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575293。

Comment: has_manyは正常に認識されていました。一度`rbenv uninstall 2.1.4`で該当のバージョンを削除してから再インストールすることでエラーが出なくなりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

内部的に何かがおかしくなっていたのか該当のバージョンのRubyを再インストールしたら認識されるようになりました。

以下のコマンドで修復しました。

```
rbenv uninstall 2.1.4
rbenv install 2.1.4
gem i bundle 
bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

僕自身はこういう警告に遭遇したことはないのですが、ありそうな原因を考えてみます。

Rubyのバージョン管理は何を使われていますか？rvm? rbenv?
rbenvの場合、`.ruby-version`ファイルをプロジェクトのルートディレクトリに置いてますか？
もしなければ作成して適切なRubyのバージョンを指定し、RubyMineを再起動してください。
（rvmは最近使っていないのでわかりません）

それでもおかしい場合はPreferenceで現在使用中のRubyバージョンを確認してください。
異様に古いバージョンが選択されたりしていませんか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Rubyのバージョンが適切であればもう一度RubyMine上からbundle installしてみてください。
（シフトキーを2回押して "bundle" と入力すれば install コマンドが選択できます）

bundle installが正常に完了すると、しばらくの間インデックスの再構築が実行されます。（画面の下の方に表示されているはずです）
再構築が完了したときに何かエラーメッセージは表示されませんか？
特に何も起きなければ正常にインストールできたはずです。

それでもダメな場合はRubyMineのHelpをじっくり読んで、自分の環境で何かおかしなところはないか調べるぐらいしかないかなーと思います。

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/rails.html

以上ご参考までに。

### 追記

rbenvはどうやってインストールしましたか？ Homebrew経由だった場合はシンボリックリンクの設定が必要になるようです。

[RubyMineでHomebrewを使ってインストールしたrbenvを認識させる - Qiita](http://qiita.com/otukutun/items/8029ad994bc516308ccd)

Comment: ありがとうございます `.ruby-version` を以前エラーが出た時に消していたので原因だったようです。ファイルを作成したら正常に認識されるようになりました。

Comment: すいません、勘違いでした。起動時の読み込みが遅かっただけで読み込みが完了したら同様のエラーが出ていました。

Comment: homebrewではなく git を使った方法でインストールしています。一度`rbenv uninstall 2.1.4`で該当のバージョンを削除してから再インストールすることでエラーが出なくなりました。どうやら何かが壊れてしまっていたようです。